# Python & Jade iteration of a dictionary : ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, flask, pyjade

I have the following dictionary i want to iterate with pyjade:

```
stations = {'ren': 'RENA', 'hum': 'Hummelvoll'}
```

In my index.jade i have the following snippet:

```
each val, index in stations
    li= index + ': ' + val
```

This raises a

> "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

error.
The snippet is directly taken from http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/

I am sure the dictonary is available to be parsed with jade.

Using `"=stations['ren']"` renders correctly to "RENA".

When i iterate a tuple or list, the page renders correctly.

Is this a bug, do i need to include something else, or does jade not support the use of dictonaries like the ones i would like to use?

Comment: The iterable returned from a dict is the keys, you should be using the keys to access the items

Comment: Dunno about jade but in python the reason would be that you have to write `stations.items()` otherwise you would iterate over the keys only. Guess its a similar issue here.

Comment: Sorry I thought this was python code but in fact it's jade which I know nada about, could you try this: `each index in stations
    li= index + ': ' + stations[index]` I have no idea whether this is valid

Comment: I fixed this problem by using the Jinja2 syntax in the jade template. Not the cleanest way to do this but it works very well.